# How to navigate to component in prod build index.html page?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have created below routing

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
 { path: "", component: SigninComponent },
    { path: "signin", component: SigninComponent },
      { path: "home", component: HomeComponent }
    ];
```

I can route successfully to Home or signin component in local host by entering the url as below.

```
http://localhost:4200/signin

http://localhost:4200/home
```

for testing i have created a prod build (npm run build:prod).

```
file://infra.corp.local/dfsshares/home/Documents/MyDashboard-Registraion/public/0.1.0/index.html
```

If i open index.html "signin" component is loading successfully.

**Now my question how i can navigate to home component by physically calling the url?**

example

```
  file://infra.corp.local/dfsshares/home/Documents/MyDashboard-Registraion/public/0.1.0/home
```

error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

please suggest..

Comment: After angular build, static files are generated, you need to put them in server in order to have routing. like apache, ngix etc. What is your exact requirement, do you want  to just view the build project?

Comment: my requirement is to redirect to home component by entering in url like as below file://infra.corp.local/dfsshares/home/Documents/MyDashboard-Registraion/home.html

Comment: This is not possible without server.

Comment: For a little bit more detail, you need some kind of server to redirect the required routes to index.html. In resolving a file:// route, anything you request is treated as asking for a file.

Comment: Have you tried vs code extension `Live Server`?